# Do you need an Irish visa if you already have a UK visa and will only visit Ireland on-board a cruise ship (without disembarking)?

Tags: visas, filipino-citizens, cruising

I am joining my husband (who is currently working on a cruise ship) in June in the port of Liverpool, UK to cruise through Ireland, Schengen, Russia and Channel Islands. I finish the cruise in Amsterdam then flying to UK and stay there for a month.

I know for sure that I will need to apply for a multiple entry tourist visa for UK, but if i won't be  going out in Irish Ports, do I still need a visa and what sort? Also, is there any way I can apply for all these visas at the same time?

I cruised in South Pacific before and I only applied for Australian visa multi-entry so it wasn't difficult at all and I used to be a seafarer as well and been to these places but obviously crew members have special application. But just wondering if there is an easy way to do it like through travel agents?

I am a Filipino Citizen.

Comment: Even if you do not disembark in the ROI and travelling as a crew supernumerary, you will still need a visa or seaman's book.

Comment: @GayotFow I assume OP will have a UK visa by then. Would that be sufficient?

Comment: I presume your husband is not an EU, EEA, or Swiss citizen, but if he were the answer might be different.

Comment: Check with the cruise line. Some require visas for all stops; others don't.

Comment: Thank you guys! @phoog husband is british but i don't think it will make any difference as I am still a Filipino Citizen. I will need Irish, Shengen & UK visas then with multiple entry stamp but i want to just have a one-time processing, if you gusy know any agencies that do these kinds of arrangements? 

Comment: You can get your Irish and Schengen visas for free thanks to the EU freedom of movement directive, because you are traveling with your British husband.

Comment: Really @phoog?  ok, i will find out more about it. Is this still effective even after Brexit?

Comment: @phoog.... Thank you so much! I have just read recent info apart from the freedom of movement.

Comment: @gednecscott once brexit is complete, it seems likely that the UK will no longer participate in the EU freedom of movement regime.  That is uncertain, though, as is the date for the completion of brexit.  This looks likely to be in 2019, but that is far from certain.

Comment: @phoog we got info from a ship's friend that i will be put in the crew manifest, so visas wont be needed But i will still need visa to travel to UK though. Good to know about the free-visa thing. Thank you! I'll keep you all posted. This might help other people as well. X

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate visa for the Republic of Ireland.

Citizens from some countries are allowed to enter the Republic of Ireland for stays less than 90 days if they have a regular UK short stay visitor visa (under the ['Short stay visa waiver programme'](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Irish+Short+Stay+Visa+Waiver+Programme)), but this programme does not cover Philippine citizens.

Comment: Is this true even if the traveler never disembarks?

Comment: @phoog Why not? You have entered Ireland and are subject to immigration regulations long before reaching the port.

Comment: Cruise ship passengers are subject to exceptions in many countries, even if they *do* disembark.

Comment: Yes @phoog only china and India are practicig Uk-irish visa scheme.

Comment: @phoog I know there are exceptions for cruise passengers in *some* countries, I am not so sure if there are exceptions in *many* countries. Not that the number of countries matters, there is AFAIK no such exception in any EU or Schengen country. Quite common are simplified immigration checks for cruise passengers, but the practical implementation of these is usually that the cruise line is trusted with identity verification and that immigration control by the authorities is done based on a passenger manifest. The passengers must still fulfill regular immigration requirements.

Comment: @gednecscott I didn't say anything about the British-Irish visa scheme, did I?

Comment: Oh no @phoog, i meant to answer your question "is this true even if the traveler never disembark?" I just found out yesterday about the Irish-UK visa scheme supporting what Tor-Einar Jambo posted as a comment.